# how to replace title field with some other field in entity reference field list?

Tags: entities

I created a content type 'country' with three fields title,description,code and i referred this content type 'country' in content type 'city' using entity reference module. In the creation page of the content type 'city' it displays a dropdown with the list of 'country's  title. every thing working fine.

but i want concatenated value of title and code in the drop down list is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a view and add the **Title** and **Code** fields.
2. Add an **Entity Reference** display to your view. In the *View edit page*, under the **Settings** for the **Format: Entity Reference list**, check one of your fields.
3. On your *City* content type, under the *Country* reference fields settings, change the target type on the *Mode* field under *Entity Selection* to **View: Filter by an entity reference view**. After selecting, the fields in that fieldset should update making your newly created view available under the **View used to select the entities** field. Select your view and save the fields settings.

Your dropdown should now have your Title and Code fields.